# iOS swiftDelegate file gives black screen on adding code, please guide

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

In sceneDelegate ,I use the below code in willConnectTo, i get the navigationController but the root view controller is a black screen, i can change its background color etc but i cannot see any view object like label, table etc,

So this is what i did, i deleted the story board, removed the entries as needed to be deleted from plist, then i add the code to my sceneDelegate, with target as ios 13, now the aim is to be able to add a navigationcontroller that i can use to move to other view controllers, in this case i use a ViewController file which come as default as my rootviewcontroller,

Now every thing works well, the naviagtion bar is also visible as you can see , but … this is where the problem come, the rootviewcontroller doesnot show any sub views, like labels, tables etc, only a black screen , i can change its color but again cannot add any sub view to it,

please guide, thanks

[image]

```
guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let vc: ViewController = ViewController()
         let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
         let win = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
         win.rootViewController = nc
 win.makeKeyAndVisible()
 window = win
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to re-order your code...

As you can see in your code you are setting the `window` property **after** making it key and visible, you should do it **before**.

Also, you can then call your `makeKeyAndVisible()` method directly from your `window` property.

Try this:

```
guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
let vc: ViewController = ViewController()
let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
let win = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
win.rootViewController = nc
window = win
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```